# Why does one random int become the same as another random int after I specifically prevent this?

Tags: java, android

In my program, two random numbers are generated. One of them (rbvalue) is between 0 and 8. The other, loadG4, is between 0 and 9. If rbvalue is ever == as loadG4, it'll be set to 9. This way, the two numbers can never be equal. For some reason, the code is flawed after the first time a button is clicked (program loops after each button click). In the code there may be excess information not relevant, I am putting it in anyway in case in clashes with the random generation and comparison that we are focusing on. Here is the code:

```
Random random = new Random();
int rbselector = random.nextInt(4);    //These three are declared outside of onCreate.
int loadG4 = random.nextInt(10);

for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
    int rbvalue = random.nextInt(9);
    if (rbvalue == loadG4) {
        rbvalue = 9;
    }
    selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + rbvalue);
}
selectrb[rbselector].setText("" + loadG4);

for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
    selectrb[allrbA].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button clicked = (Button)v;
            String clickVal = (String)clicked.getText();
            int finalClick = Integer.valueOf(clickVal);

            if (finalClick == loadG4) {
                score++;
                for (int allrbA = 0; allrbA < 4; allrbA++) {
                    int rbvalue = random.nextInt(9);
                    loadG4 = random.nextInt(10);
                    if (rbvalue == loadG4) {
                        rbvalue = 9;
                    }
                    selectrb[allrbA].setText("" + rbvalue);
                }
                number.setText("" + loadG4);
                rbselector = random.nextInt(4);
                selectrb[rbselector].setText("" + loadG4);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: *Trying a different method won't work. This has been tested and it appears the problem must be coming from something else in my code, but I'm unsure what it is.*

Comment: You should really extract stuff into subfunctions for clarity, it would help reason about your code.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Which random int "becomes" another? I mean, you update `rbselector` and `loadG4` all the time, but... no clue what context this is running in, what the specific issue is, etc. You need to be more explicit.

Comment: @DaveNewton I specified in the post, what is it you don't get? Of course only reading the title wouldn't be clear enough. LoadG4 should never equal rbvalue. To do this, I set rbvalue to 9 each time they are equal, though this doesn't actually work for some reason.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking (along with several other people). Try debugging outer putting a watch on the variable. Without any context around where there issue is happening it's impossible to help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure if I understand your question but my understanding is that you have two integers which you want both to be generated randomly, one between 0 and 9, and the other between 0 and 8; these numbers should never equal the same thing. Also, I wrote my solution with the assumption that .nextInt() is exclusive, you should confirm this in the java documentation however.

Here is how I would solve this problem:

```
Random r = new Random();
int a = r.nextInt(10);
int b = r.nextInt(9);

while(a==b)
      b = r.nextInt(9);
```

This simply generates two random ints and in the event that they are equal to each other will continue randomly generating a value for int b until it is something not equal to int a.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work either. Both methods I provided and yours should work, they aren't for some reason. I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: what kind of error is it causing (compile, logic, run)? If it is a compile or run time error, can you post the error message? Also, are you running in an IDE and if so which one?

Comment: As mentioned, the error is that another copy of loadG4 is outputted. This is not meant to happen, I'm using the Android Studio IDE. No compilation error or anything, I can literally see what the error is (a value equal to loadG4 being outputted by an rbvalue).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by outputted, I don't see any return statements or println statements. Based on what you said, I would imagine that whatever line of code you have which "outputs" the values maybe is before your code which checks that the two values are not equal, and then changes them if they are equal.

Comment: you may want to consider adding a method dedicated to generating the random numbers and checking that they aren't equal. This would improve object oriented design and potentially make it easier to find the logic error / bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but moving `loadG4 = random.nextInt(10);` above the for loop resolves this issue, anyone know why? If anyone can answer this, I'll mark that as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using two times a similar but different piece of code.
The first loop you do works correctly. The one in the listener doesn't.

You're setting loadG4 to a different value at each loop turn, which makes the equality test in previous loop turns dull. You need to set loadG4 once and for all before the loop, so that each iteration tests correctly for equality with this value.